# What is a common way to communicate to users that their package will ship in more than one box?

Tags: e-commerce, process, shipping

I've got a project where I'm going to be working on the way an eCommerce website will be communicating to the user that their purchase will be shipped in two boxes. I'm most interested in eCommerce examples of how other companies have tackled this problem.

Maybe you have a screenshot with blurred personal info of a shipping confirmation email or receipt email?

Maybe you can describe your encounter?

I guess I'm just trying to get my finger on the pulse of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different ways I have seen this done, Some companies tell you prior to you submitting payment while for other companies you see that once you have paid and look on the "order tracking" pages.

A specific example which I feel works very well is as follows:

The company is [Very](http://www.Very.co.uk).

When you submit an order you are taken to the order delivery screen where you can see which items will be sent in separate packages (and also either the estimated deliver dates for each package or you are given options as to when you want items delivering). This company also allows you to specify different delivery address for each package.

[image: Delivery information screen]